# Able to find the largest product for Project Euler #8, but what are the numbers that resulted this largest product?

Tags: python

The following is the updated question from [Project Euler #8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8):

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

I was able to solve this question for the largest product. But I am also trying to find which sequence of 13 digits resulted the largest product. How to do I optimize or improve my code to get 13 digit sequence of the largest product?

```
    largest_product = 0
    # number = '1000 digit number from the question'

    for i in number:
        if len(number) > 12:
            result = 1
            for j in range(13):
                z = int(number[j])
                result = result * z
            if result > largest_product:
                largest_product = result
            number = number[1:]

    print(largest_product)
```

Python Version: 3.7. OS: Windows 10.

P.S: This is my first ever question asking on stackoverflow. Forgive if any rules have been missed.

Comment: i suggest posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: tips: 1. don't reassign what you are looping over. 2. the current solution takes O(mn) time where n=1000 and m=13. You can actually do O(n) time using a sliding window approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple matter to save the position of those digits:

```
        if result > largest_product:
            largest_product = result
            largest_digits = number[:13]
        number = number[1:]

print(largest_product, largest_digits)
```

As others have noted, there are "better" ways to do this.  For one thing, re-creating your list on every iteration is expensive.  Instead, leave the original sequence intact, and move a sliding window through it.

Second, note that you're converting each digit to `int` multiple times -- you can avoid that with the sliding window (convert only the new digit), or convert all the digits at the start and work with a list of integers.

Comment: that was embarrassing to miss such a simple logic. i'm new to python and looking into the points you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You're recreating `number` each iteration, which is highly wasteful. You should do a loop over the index rather the elements, so you can use the same `number`. You also can simply update `result` rather than recalculating it: each time you move the window over, you're losing one digit and gaining another, so you can just divide and multiply by the corresponding numbers (this does mean that your result will be a float rather than int, though). You can also use `reduce` to get the product, rather than using a for-loop. You can also convert the elements of `number` to numbers outside the loop:

```
number_as_reals = [float(_) for _ in number]
current_result = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), number_as_reals[0:13]) 
best_result = current_result
for i in range(1,len(number)-13):
     current_result = current_result*number_as_reals[i+12]/number_as_reals[i-1]
     if current_result > best_result:
         best_result = current_result # You can also do best_result = max(best_result, current_result)
```

You might also want to convert everything to logs so that you can use addition rather than multiplication. This does require some error handling of the zeros:

```
import math
import numpy as np
number_as_logs = [math.log(float(_)) if _ else -np.inf for _ in number] # You can also just use a really negative number, such as -1000, rather than -np.inf
current_result = sum(number_as_logs[0:13]) 
best_result = current_result
for i in range(1,len(number)-13):
     current_result = current_result+number_as_logs[i+12]-number_as_logs[i-1]
     if current_result > best_result:
         best_result = current_result
```

And if you want it without [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), it would be

```
import math
import numpy as np
number_as_logs = [math.log(float(_)) if _ else -np.inf for _ in number] 
window_size = 13
current_result = sum(number_as_logs[0:window_size]) 
best_result = current_result
for i in range(1,len(number)-window_size):
     current_result = current_result+number_as_logs[i+window_size-1]-number_as_logs[i-1]
     if current_result > best_result:
         best_result = current_result
```

Comment: that was a detailed answer. i have so far haven't come across lamda and reduce. i will look into these concepts and apply in future codes.